# Django Admin Search - returning duplicates when search_field includes many-to-many

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm receiving multiple duplicate objects when using Django Admin search.

I have two models involved. Organisation and OrgAlias(Organisation Alias). Each Organisation may have multiple aliases and each alias may be attached to multiple Organisations.

The models:

```
class OrgAlias(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    aliases = models.ManyToManyField(OrgAlias)
    ...
```

My Django Admin class:

```
class OrganisationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['aliases__name']
    ...
```

I've tried overriding the ModelAdmin get_search_results function with various strategies. e.g.

```
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term) 
        queryset = queryset.distinct()
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

The result is always the same. If I have 3 aliases attached to and organisation. The organisation will appear 3 times in the search results.

Similar queries work fine in the shell. It's just in django admin the problem appears.

Is there a simple fix or workaround for this?

Comment: I also spotted that the search totals are correct. i.e. the note next to the search button says "2 results (x total)" which is correct and the footer of the table says "2 organisations" which is correct.

However, the table has 3 entries. 2 identical lines belonging to the same organisations which has 2 aliases.

 The issue appears to be in the rendering of the table.

Comment: Further research indicates this is something to do with ordering. I started to see the same thing in the shell. Where any organisations with multiple aliases would be returned x times their number of aliases.

I commented this out in the Organisation model:
    # class Meta:
    #     ordering = ["aliases__name",]

and the shell started returning single instances.

I also have a field in admin that is based on a function that returns the primary alias of each org. When the table was sorted on that field it returned duplicates. When not it didn't. Looking at re visiting how I show this.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing:
I believe the duplicates to be expected behaviour.

I have multiple aliases (or names) attached to organisations. If I use any ordering (e.g. order_by) functionality on the many-to-many alias field it makes sense that each alias would appear at a different place in the order. Hence one duplicate for each alias.

I'm changing the model to sort with a non-many-to-many method.